# Mp3 player with messed up buttons

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button

I'm working on a MP3 Player and i just realized my main_activity.xml is messed up

I have 3 Buttons, Previous, Play/Pause and Next as shown [here](http://i1250.photobucket.com/albums/hh522/Slipfreak900/Capturadepantalla2014-06-15152744_zps473e809c.png)

I only have 1 reputation point, so, no image uploads for now.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="7"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Caratula" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btnprevious"
            android:onClick="click" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" />

        <Button                          
            android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/play"
            android:onClick="click"  />



        <View
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/next"
            android:onClick="click" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'll Appreciate the help here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you want the buttons to be laid out but try this for the `LinearLayout` containing the buttons...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnprevious"
        android:onClick="click" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button                          
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:onClick="click"  />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/next"
        android:onClick="click" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can get rid of the `android:weightSum` attribute - it's optional and the total weight sum will be calculated as the sum of all of the `android:layout_weight` attributes of the widgets in the `LinearLayout`. Using the above, each `Button` and `View` will be apportioned one-fifth of the width of the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I got a few "Nested weights are bad for performance" warnings. Should i delete the lines causing this error?

Comment: No. That's just Android Lint being pedantic. Sure, nesting things too much (not just weights but nested layouts) *might* affect performance but it doesn't mean it actually will. Test it out and if it works then fine. If you can tidy it up and reduce things then do so.